# Selecting only one out of many: Differential equation

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, output-formatting, conditional, table

I have the following code:

```
Clear["Global`*"]

K1 = 12;
K3 = 195/10;
eo = 885/100;
ea = 145/10;
L = 1;

ele[E2_] = -(1/(2 K3)) L (E2^2 ea eo Sin[2 g[z]] - (K1 - K3) Sin[
       2 g[z]] g'[z]^2 + (K1 + K3 + (K1 - K3) Cos[2 g[z]]) g''[z]) // 
  Simplify

pnd = ParametricNDSolveValue[{ele[E2] == 0, g[0] == 0, g[L] == 0}, 
  g, {z, 0, L}, {E2, gp0}, 
  Method -> 
   "BoundaryValues" -> {"Shooting", 
     "StartingInitialConditions" -> {g[0] == 0, g'[0] == gp0}}]

Plot[Evaluate@Table[pnd[E2, gp0][z], {gp0, 0, 15, 0.05}, {E2, 0, 2}],
 {z, 0, L},
 PlotRange -> All]
```

the output is:

[image]

The circles are added by me (in paint) just to represent, what would be final out put.

So for E2=0 the output is zero, for all gp0. So, I just want to select the first value of gp0 at which the output is zero from {z,0,L}. Similarly, For E2, 1 and 2 at different gp0 the output graphs can be zero, lie above and below the x axis and entirely above the x axis. I just want to select the first gp0 for E2=1 and E2=2 at which the graphs is entirely above the x axis.

such as

```
aa=Evaluate[Table[pnd[E2, gp0][z], {gp0, 0, 15, 0.05}, {E2, 0, 2}],
 {z, 0, L}]
```

For  E2=0
select the first gp0 at which aa lie on x-axis {z,0,L} "meaning zero"

For E2=1 to E2<=2
select the first gp0 at which aa is entirely above the x-axis {z,0,L}

so the final plot will contain only three outputs (three lines) for E2=0, E2=1 and E2=2 (as shown in the figure the circled ones).

I can do this manually but the E2 values can change from 0 to 30 and parameters K1, K3 and e can also change and this means do the manual thing again and again. So, want to do programmatically.

If I use the following commands, the errors are,

[image]

However, the above two commands should work but there are some basic errors that I do not understand. The output will look like this,

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ITawk.png

Also, in addition to the above, here (https://i.stack.imgur.com/ITawk.png) now there are multiple functions that give zero, 0.3 and 1.2. However, I want to select only one function that gives zero, 0.3 and 1.2 and discard the rest.

Comment: Perhaps `Select[Flatten@aa,  AllTrue[# /. z -> "ValuesOnGrid", 1. + # >= 1. &] &]` or `Select[Flatten@aa,  AllTrue[# /. z -> "ValuesOnGrid", # >= 0. &] &]` depending on what you want to count as "zero."

Comment: Thanks! it does not work.

Comment: I get this, https://i.stack.imgur.com/ITawk.png, which appears to me to be what you indicated you wanted.  Please update the question to clarify what exactly you want and why is wrong about the `Select[..]` code output.

Comment: @MichaelE2 That's exactly what I want. However, I updated the question and now the basic errors which I am getting are mentioned above. Also, I added the additional part which I am expecting for the final output.

Comment: I believe you have a syntax error. Try `aa=Table[pnd[E2, gp0][z], {gp0, 0, 15, 0.05}, {E2, 0, 2}]`.  I think you want `aa` to be the table of solutions and not to include the plotting range for `z`.

Comment: @MichaelE2 many thanks! I was able to figure it out. aa=Table[pnd[E2, gp0][z], {gp0, 0, 15, 0.05}, {E2, 0, 2}] and then  Plot[Select[Flatten@aa,  AllTrue[# /. z -> "ValuesOnGrid", 1. + # >= 1. &] &],{z,0,L}] or Plot[Select[Flatten@aa,  AllTrue[# /. z -> "ValuesOnGrid", # >= 0. &] &],{z,0,L}]  I am getting the same output that I mentioned in the question, not the one that you added in the comments. Can you please mention it in the answer, also if you have an idea for discarding the duplicates, please mention it.